# wp_update_post behaves differently for different user role

Tags: wp-update-post

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "section_name": "Objective",
      "data": "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Test</span>",
      "key": "ref"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am updating the above JSON data as plain text through wp_update_post

```
data = <<<EOD
{"sections":[{"section_name":"Objective","data":"<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Test</span>","key":"ref"}]}
EOD;
    $new = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $data,
                'post_author'    => $userid,
                'post_status'   => 'pending',
                'post_type' => 'post'
              );
         $id = wp_insert_post($new );
```

The data is saved exactly like it passed with escaped slashes only on "Administrator" login.

On all other user types, for ex "subscriber", the slashes are automatically stripped when saved. which makes it invalid JSON.

How to save the exact passed data for all user types?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a new user type with unfiltered_html set to true

```
$result = add_role(
    'jobseeker',
    __( 'Job Seeker' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true, 
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => true,
        'delete_published_posts' => true, 
        'upload_files' => true,
        'edit_others_posts' => false, 
        'delete_others_posts' => false,
        'unfiltered_html' => true, //this line does the magic


    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}
```